# Why the widespread dependency on samba? Unnecesary coupling?

Tags: apt, samba, mate

What is the purpose of samba. I have been thinking it is a file sharing protocol for Microsoft file systems. Is this presumption incorrect or has samba been brought inappropriately into general system files?

For example :

I use NFS and SSHFS for my remote shares. What do I lose by

```
 apt purge *samba*
```

Trying it out I get :

```
 The following packages will be REMOVED:
   gvfs-backends* libsmbclient* mate-desktop-environment-core* mpv*
   python3-samba* samba-common* samba-common-bin* samba-libs* 
   smbclient*
```

I see in this list a few items whose *dependency* on samba is questionable.

Comment: Removing the **mate-desktop-environment-core** package seems dangerous; not worth it, IMHO. I wouldn't do this.

Comment: @ajgringo619 I've changed the focus of the question since you posted your comment. It was a good comment then and I thank you for it.   I'm asking now *why* the dependency of  a desktop environment on an optional file-sharing service -- and a Microsoft protocol? Perhaps there is a samba library we need but if so surely that should be decoupled.

Comment: I can't say why certain distros couple programs with core packages that *should* be removable. I ran into the same thing with flatpak when I run installed Mint 18 (this has since been fixed).

Comment: @ajgringo619 Okay. I'll post over on the MATE forum.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit wide question.

The exact `samba` package is the SMB/CIFS [server](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/samba), but you have asked APT to remove `*samba*`, which includes some Samba-related libraries for client-side parts.

For example it is a bad idea to allow removal of `gvfs-backends`. This will end with losing SMB/CIFS support in Caja file-manager (fork of Nautilus) and other related applications. In current heterogeneous world I think that it is a bad idea as SMB/CIFS is most cross-platform file-transfer protocol for NASes and computers.

By removing of `smbclient` you will lose the console functionality for SMB/CIFS shares.

But removing of `mate-desktop-environment-core` is almost safe as it contain only [4 non-essential files](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/all/mate-desktop-environment-core/filelist).

So I would suggest to keep all `*samba*` components at their places.